# What's GAN's Input-size Limitations?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, generative-models, gan

I am interested in GAN for generating synthetic data. I am studying the input limitations for GAN starting from which GAN is no longer usable.

I have found many applications that use GANs for 1024x1024 or 3072x3072 inputs. I haven't found implementations of much higher input dimensionality. This is important because for time series data for example, we might easily be interested in an input-size of tens of thousands or over.

How does GAN behave when the input size increases tremendously (over a few thousands)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think is more a "how are we going to train that monstrosity?"... and also, finding a dataset that is 3072x3072 per sample, to be representative of the true distribution (which is what the GAN should learn), must be enormous in memory

Comment: GANs suffer tremendously from instability with larger image inputs. It actually took a while for research to even find ways to get 1024px images to work. I'm not sure what you mean by the time series data. Are you talking about non-image data? Because technically a 1024x1024 image has over 1 million inputs. 256x256 images have about 65k inputs. So tens of thousands of inputs isn't really that big of a deal. Just not sure what you're asking